# Program crashes when trying to open HyperCard stack

Tags: livecode, hypercard

I get a crash when I try to open a HyperCard stack to convert it to LiveCode format. Using LiveCode Community 7.0.1. Are there any reasons for this that anyone knows? Here's a bit from the problem details:

```
Process:               LiveCode-Community [69341]
Path:                  /Applications/LiveCode Community 7.0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/LiveCode-Community
Identifier:            com.runrev.livecode
Version:               7.0.1.10020 [RC 2] (7.0.1.10020 [RC 2])
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           LiveCode-Community [69341]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2015-07-01 11:04:58.427 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        F145239F-111C-2DD7-D8F5-0EA338CB5568

Sleep/Wake UUID:       40F13F91-3DAC-4E13-A409-3F01E823A448

Time Awake Since Boot: 420000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-0000000000942000 [ 9476K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/LiveCode Community 7.0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/LiveCode-Community

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x94305920 strlen + 16
1   com.runrev.livecode             0x001b0ab8 MCObject::setname_cstring(char const*) + 40
2   com.runrev.livecode             0x0017635a MCHcbmap::build() + 1562
3   com.runrev.livecode             0x001776b3 MCHcbkgd::build(MCHcstak*, MCStack*) + 339
4   com.runrev.livecode             0x001796a4 MCHcstak::build() + 1124
5   com.runrev.livecode             0x00179ad5 hc_import(__MCString*, MCSystemFileHandle*, MCStack*&) + 277
6   com.runrev.livecode             0x00124d76 MCDispatch::doreadfile(__MCString*, __MCString*, MCSystemFileHandle*&, MCStack*&) + 2086
7   com.runrev.livecode             0x0012512d MCDispatch::loadfile(__MCString*, MCStack*&) + 493
8   com.runrev.livecode             0x0012717c MCDispatch::findstackname(__MCName*) + 188
9   com.runrev.livecode             0x0020f0f4 MCStack::findstackname_string(__MCString*) + 84
10  com.runrev.livecode             0x00104902 MCGo::findstack(MCExecContext&, __MCString*, Chunk_term, MCCard*&) + 322
11  com.runrev.livecode             0x00104b53 MCGo::exec_ctxt(MCExecContext&) + 307
12  com.runrev.livecode             0x00171689 MCHandler::exec(MCExecContext&, MCParameter*) + 1081
13  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b2ca7 MCObject::exechandler(MCHandler*, MCParameter*) + 471
14  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b3bc1 MCObject::handleself(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*) + 193
15  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b3c82 MCObject::handle(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*, MCObject*) + 50
16  com.runrev.livecode             0x002d3bf2 MCKeywordsExecCommandOrFunction(MCExecContext&, bool, MCHandler*, MCParameter*, __MCName*, unsigned short, unsigned short, bool, bool) + 866
17  com.runrev.livecode             0x00215e92 MCComref::exec_ctxt(MCExecContext&) + 98
18  com.runrev.livecode             0x002d3fc2 MCKeywordsExecuteStatements(MCExecContext&, MCStatement*, Exec_errors) + 162
19  com.runrev.livecode             0x002d4183 MCKeywordsExecuteRepeatStatements(MCExecContext&, MCStatement*, unsigned short, unsigned short, bool&) + 35
20  com.runrev.livecode             0x002d471e MCKeywordsExecRepeatFor(MCExecContext&, MCStatement*, MCExpression*, MCVarref*, File_unit, unsigned short, unsigned short) + 1246
21  com.runrev.livecode             0x0018e529 MCRepeat::exec_ctxt(MCExecContext&) + 105
22  com.runrev.livecode             0x002d3fc2 MCKeywordsExecuteStatements(MCExecContext&, MCStatement*, Exec_errors) + 162
23  com.runrev.livecode             0x002d4158 MCKeywordsExecIf(MCExecContext&, MCExpression*, MCStatement*, MCStatement*, unsigned short, unsigned short) + 88
24  com.runrev.livecode             0x0018da4c MCIf::exec_ctxt(MCExecContext&) + 60
25  com.runrev.livecode             0x00171689 MCHandler::exec(MCExecContext&, MCParameter*) + 1081
26  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b2ca7 MCObject::exechandler(MCHandler*, MCParameter*) + 471
27  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b3bc1 MCObject::handleself(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*) + 193
28  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b3c82 MCObject::handle(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*, MCObject*) + 50
29  com.runrev.livecode             0x00123c41 MCDispatch::handle(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*, MCObject*) + 353
30  com.runrev.livecode             0x00201412 MCStack::handle(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*, MCObject*) + 482
31  com.runrev.livecode             0x00201412 MCStack::handle(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*, MCObject*) + 482
32  com.runrev.livecode             0x000db72a MCCard::handle(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*, MCObject*) + 362
33  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b3cbe MCObject::handle(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*, MCObject*) + 110
34  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b3cbe MCObject::handle(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*, MCObject*) + 110
35  com.runrev.livecode             0x002d3bf2 MCKeywordsExecCommandOrFunction(MCExecContext&, bool, MCHandler*, MCParameter*, __MCName*, unsigned short, unsigned short, bool, bool) + 866
36  com.runrev.livecode             0x00215e92 MCComref::exec_ctxt(MCExecContext&) + 98
37  com.runrev.livecode             0x002d3fc2 MCKeywordsExecuteStatements(MCExecContext&, MCStatement*, Exec_errors) + 162
38  com.runrev.livecode             0x002d3ee7 MCKeywordsExecSwitch(MCExecContext&, MCExpression*, MCExpression**, unsigned int, short, unsigned short*, MCStatement*, unsigned short, unsigned short) + 567
39  com.runrev.livecode             0x0018eeaf MCSwitch::exec_ctxt(MCExecContext&) + 95
40  com.runrev.livecode             0x00171689 MCHandler::exec(MCExecContext&, MCParameter*) + 1081
41  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b2ca7 MCObject::exechandler(MCHandler*, MCParameter*) + 471
42  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b3bc1 MCObject::handleself(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*) + 193
43  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b3c82 MCObject::handle(Handler_type, __MCName*, MCParameter*, MCObject*) + 50
44  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b1911 MCObject::message(__MCName*, MCParameter*, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char) + 433
45  com.runrev.livecode             0x001b1723 MCObject::message_with_valueref_args(__MCName*, void*) + 115
46  com.runrev.livecode             0x002f45e0 MCPlatformHandleMenuSelect(MCPlatformMenu*, unsigned int) + 464
47  com.runrev.livecode             0x002e00ef -[com_runrev_livecode_MCMenuDelegate menuItemSelected:] + 207
48  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x9aa47853 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
49  com.apple.AppKit                0x938407ee __36-[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke + 51
50  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x90846c03 _os_activity_initiate + 89
51  com.apple.AppKit                0x93840707 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 602
52  com.apple.AppKit                0x938403ad -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 479
53  com.apple.AppKit                0x9384009e -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 162
54  com.apple.AppKit                0x9383f71a -[NSMenu _performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:sendAccessibilityNotification:] + 79
55  com.apple.AppKit                0x93911e3b __38-[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:]_block_invoke + 52
56  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x90846c03 _os_activity_initiate + 89
57  com.apple.AppKit                0x93911dff -[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:] + 141
58  com.apple.AppKit                0x93911d5e -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 45
59  com.apple.AppKit                0x93911d29 -[NSMenuItem _internalPerformActionThroughMenuIfPossible] + 106
60  com.apple.AppKit                0x93911b82 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 120
61  com.apple.AppKit                0x938270b7 NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 679
62  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9526f5a4 _InvokeEventHandlerUPP(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*, long (*)(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)) + 36
63  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x950ad681 DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 2291
64  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x950ac65c SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 402
65  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x950c0f25 SendEventToEventTarget + 88
66  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9526f422 SendHICommandEvent(unsigned long, HICommand const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned char, void const*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventRef**) + 447
67  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9513327c SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 72
68  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95133220 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 207
69  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x951330db FinishMenuSelection(SelectionData*, MenuResult*, MenuResult*) + 145
70  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x952c1517 MenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, unsigned long, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) + 775
71  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9513387b _HandleMenuSelection2 + 512
72  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95133665 _HandleMenuSelection + 55
73  com.apple.AppKit                0x937387f6 _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 359
74  com.apple.AppKit                0x93667ae9 _DPSNextEvent + 1710
75  com.apple.AppKit                0x93666dc5 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 350
76  com.runrev.livecode             0x002da8e9 MCPlatformWaitForEvent(double, bool) + 505
77  com.runrev.livecode             0x002f251c MCScreenDC::wait(double, unsigned char, unsigned char) + 460
78  com.runrev.livecode             0x0024568d X_main_loop_iteration() + 237
79  com.runrev.livecode             0x002f6673 MCPlatformHandleApplicationRun(bool&) + 19
80  com.runrev.livecode             0x002d9ef4 -[com_runrev_livecode_MCApplicationDelegate runMainLoop] + 84
81  com.apple.Foundation            0x95dcb166 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 489
82  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9148a006 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
83  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x91489ab4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1316
84  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9150554f __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 351
85  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x91441531 __CFRunLoopRun + 2081
86  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x91440aa6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 390
87  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9144090b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
88  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x950d38f8 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 262
89  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x950d3503 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 192
90  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x950d342c _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 99
91  com.apple.AppKit                0x93667721 _DPSNextEvent + 742
92  com.apple.AppKit                0x93666dc5 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 350
93  com.apple.AppKit                0x9365b77c -[NSApplication run] + 907
94  com.runrev.livecode             0x002dd057 main + 759
95  com.runrev.livecode             0x00002925 start + 53
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a LiveCode bug. LiveCode should not crash and any crash is to be treated as a bug.

Second, there are a few reasons why a HyperCard stack can cause LiveCode to crash. To avoid this, try the following steps.

- Turn off messages when importing a HyperCard stack. HyperCard scripts
  may be slightly incompatible with LiveCode and the combination of
  problems with LiveCode's debugger and problems in the HyperTalk
  scripts may result in a crash.
- Make sure to compact the HyperCard stack in HyperCard before taking
  it to the Mac OS X environment. Garbage in the stack can cause a
  crash.
- Before copying the stack from Mac OS 9 to OSX, make a zip file of
  your stack and zip it on the OSX machine. This preserves a few bits
  that may be important.
- Open the stack in HyperCard and go through all the cards. If there is
  a corrupt card in the stack, copy all cards except for the corrupt
  card, to a different HyperCard stack and import that into LiveCode.